# Accessibility for Page View Controller

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility

We are working for a health group making an app which should be also implemented with Accessibility for blind - which gives a voice over of the elements.

I have developed a sample screen - which is actually a tutorial that gets launched on first installation. The thing what I am not getting the default behavior on the below Page View Controller is (when voice over is enabled)
1. 3 finger swipe to left of right is not moving to the other page.
2. One finger swipe to right should move the focus to the next control. Here, the page dots. The focus is not going to the paging dots.

Can someone please give a clue.
I have implemented the paging usual way, with UIAccesibiliy labels and hints. 
[image]

Comment: You haven't provided very much information about the problem or its context in your app. What happens instead of what you expect? What have you done to fix it?